# Apache mod_ssl configuration for PCI compliance

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, pci-dss

I need to ensure PCI compliance by limiting mod_ssl to SSLv3 and TLSv1, and ensuring long keys. I've tried the following configuration, but certain combinations of SSLv2 seems to still be valid:

```
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:+SHA1:+MD5:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
```

What should the SSLCipherSuite configuration look like to completely disable SSLv2 and meet the PCI requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I currently use for a PCI compliant Apache configuration:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!EXP:!NULL:!ADH:!LOW
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: The userdir module also needs to be disabled. It seems to be loaded by default on Ubuntu and Debian.

Comment: As noted by Mat, the rewrite rules can be replaced with "TraceEnable Off" on Apache 2.x

Comment: Would it be better to disable all and specifically enable TLSv1 and SSLv3, rather than enable all and disable SSLv2?

Comment: Same difference.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol  You could argue disable all would be a better approach.  However, new protocols are likely to be more secure rather than less.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Apache 2.0+ you can avoid the rewrite rules that Warner mentioned and replace them with just:

```
TraceEnable Off
```

Answer (score 1):

The protocols can be disabled with the SSLProtocol statement as such:

```
SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
```